# Optaplanner: The selectionList contains 2 times the same selection

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

I am new to optplanner and playing around with using it to solve a timetabling problem however after all the setup, when I try to solve the problem, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The selectionList contains 2 times the same selection (c0001{t000}-0 @ null + null) and (c0001{t000}-1 @ null + null).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.decorator.WeightFactorySelectionSorter.sort(WeightFactorySelectionSorter.java:58)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.decorator.SortingEntitySelector.constructCache(SortingEntitySelector.java:44)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.SelectionCacheLifecycleBridge.phaseStarted(SelectionCacheLifecycleBridge.java:49)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:39)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:47)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:39)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.AbstractSelector.phaseStarted(AbstractSelector.java:47)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.event.PhaseLifecycleSupport.firePhaseStarted(PhaseLifecycleSupport.java:39)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.placer.AbstractEntityPlacer.phaseStarted(AbstractEntityPlacer.java:41)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.phaseStarted(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:124)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:67)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:214)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
```

Has anyone come across this before and can you please help if you have.

Comment: [Duplicated here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/optaplanner-dev/xVKy6fgDxns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem in your dataset (or in a domain object's equals() method).

> The selectionList contains 2 times the same selection (c0001{t000}-0 @ null + null) and (c0001{t000}-1 @ null + null).

It thinks that these 2 lectures are the same:

- c0001...-0 // Lecture 0 of course 0001
- c0001...-1 // Lecture 1 of course 0001

Obviously they are not equal, because they have a different lectureIndexInCourse.

Lecture inherits it's equals method from AbstractPersistable, which does equality based on id.

My bet is that your Lectures in your dataset either have a null id or there are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks alot Geoffrey. It was a problem of a lack null ids on the Lecture objects.